# Request file() is null in api Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a route in my API right in Laravel for an iOS app that lets you upload images that I got form this tutorial https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-file-upload-storage-download/
and when I tried to upload the file it turns null.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Fileentry;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class FileEntryController extends Controller
{


    public function add() {

        $file = Request::file('filefield');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
        $entry = new Fileentry();
        $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;

        $entry->save();

        return redirect('fileentry');

    }
}
```

Route:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');


$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->post('fileentry/add',array(
        'as' => 'addentry',
        'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\FileEntryController@add'
    ));
}
```

the user doesn't interact with the web page is all through the app

Other information that maybe the cause of the problem is that i'm using Postman to upload the image to the laravel app (Method: POST, through the binary section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `form-data` method from postman and add a parameter as file type.

Keep in mind that the key of the parameter must be equal to the key you're trying to get in backend. In your case it is `filefield`

```
$file = Request::file('filefield');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html form add this attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: yeah, the thing is that is an app and I don't have any views in my project, I want to be able to upload it without a form